# Line intergral around a closed path

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Q: Evaluate the closed line intergral $ \oint xdy $ anti-clockwise around the triangle with vetricies $(a,0), (0,0),$ and $(0,b)$

For this section I've reduced the line sections to:

$ C1: x = x, y = 0 ; 0 \leqslant x\leqslant a$

$C2: x=x, y=y; a \leqslant x\leqslant 0 ; 0 \leqslant y\leqslant b$

$C3: x=0, y = y; b \leqslant y\leqslant 0$

However, I'm not sure how to reduce the line sections down to parametrized form to evaluate the integral. Where do go from here? Have I approached this problem incorrectly?

Comment: Seems easier to use Green's theorem instead of three line integrals here?

Comment: C2 is definitely wrong. Fix it.

Comment: How so? I start at the origin then go towards (a,0), then up to (0,b), then back down to (0,0) right?

Comment: A *relation* between $x$ and $y$ is required. Find the straight line passing through the points $(a,0)$ and $(0,b)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a triangle including the point (0,0) your equations aren't correct, first segment of line from (0,0) to (b,0) i described with equation $y=0$, the second one from point (b,0) to (a,0) is described with line segment $y=-ax/b+a$ and the third line segment is defined with an equation $x=0$, now you can build your integral from thees three parts, with each part having its own parametric equations, only thing you have to take care are the bounds for each line segment, for example line segment 2, is described fully with the following:
$$ y=-\frac{a}{b}x+a,x=t,y=-\frac{a}{b}t+a$$ with t in the following bounds: $$ t_1=a,t_2=0 $$ because we are to go anticlockwise around the triangle.